# Angular (7) loading wrong lazy module

Tags: angular

Here are routes in my eager HomeModule which is just below AppModule:

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'welcome',
        component: WelcomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'data',
        loadChildren: '@libs/data#DataModule',
        data: {
          expectedPermission: environment.routePermissions.data
        },
        canLoad: [PermissionGuard]
      },
      // {
      //   path: 'data-two',
      //   loadChildren: '@libs/data/src#DataTwoModule',
      //   data: {
      //     expectedPermission: environment.routePermissions.dataTwo
      //   },
      //   canLoad: [PermissionGuard]
      // },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
]),
```

Here are those in DataTwoModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: `maintain/edit/:id`,
    component: DataTwoEditComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: DataTwoListComoponent
  }
];
```

and in DataModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: `maintain/edit/:id`,
    component: DataEditComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'list',
    component: DataListComoponent
  }
];
```

enableTracing shows me that the url is resolved correctly, the NavigationEnd is `BASEURL/home/data/list` yet Angular is rendering DataTwoListComoponent for me. As you can see in HomeComponent I have even commented out the path to DataTwoModule. How is it possible it is still served? Only when I comment out the routes from DataTwoModule, Angular serves correctly DataModule for me.

The components are linked correctly (the @libs part); the app was working before; I just changed some route-names. The routes are also not exported out of their files, so they are not mixed up. What is going on here? How can I debug this other than using enableTracing?

Comment: Till now, it is hard to debug angular routing issues, i suggest to `console log` every starting point in your modules to know how the router navigation is running. Also i think it is a good when two routes start with the same word `data` and `data-two` to use `pathMatch: 'full'` because as i remember (not sure) they use some regex check to distinguish between paths.

Comment: @Nour what exactly would I log inside a module's class? The problem is that the route is correct, just not linked to the right module. So logging for activatedroute or something similar is not going to help I think. Maybe an interceptor for the http-client would help instead, logging which module it requested lazily?

Comment: @Phill you can add `console log` at you module constructor.

Comment: @Nour well both components get loaded on login together with home-module (which is onload), so logging the constructor calls in each of home's children is not very informative

Comment: I use as workaround the paths 'data-one-list' and 'data-two-list' now, which makes the url bigger and redundant, but it works. If anyone know a proper solution, please post an answer :)